# Dependency Injection with Navigation Controller as Initial View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependency-injection, uinavigationcontroller

None of the tutorials I've seen on how to setup dependency injection, for sharing state, have a Navigation Controller as the root view controller. I've tried the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // Set custom settings for UINavigationController
        let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navigationBarAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
        navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9686274529, green: 0.78039217, blue: 0.3450980484, alpha: 1)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        
        // dependency injection
        let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
        homeViewController.bidDetailsController = BidDetailsController()
        
        return true
    }
```

but since I have HomeViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller, the BidDetailsController is never actually injected into HomeViewController. The result is that when I try to use any values inside BidDetailsController, in any of the views throughout the app, I always get an error that it is nil. How can I solve this issue? How can I inject BidDetailsController ***through*** the Navigation Controller (which is the initial vc) to my HomeViewController?

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var bidDetailsController: BidDetailsController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "HOME"
        bidDetailsController = BidDetailsController()
    }
    
    @IBAction func menuBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Show Menu")
    }
    
    @IBAction func newBidBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToInfoSegue", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let infoViewController = segue.destination as? InfoViewController {
            infoViewController.bidDetailsController = bidDetailsController
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
class BidDetailsController {
    var exampleVariableOne = String()
    var exampleVariableTwo = Bool()
}
```

Comment: If you are using a storyboard to create your root view controller then nothing you do in `didFinishLaunching` will have an affect on the view controller hierarchy.  You can use [`@IBSegueAction`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9296192-improving-storyboard-segues-with-ibsegueaction) to support dependency injection

Comment: Yes, I'm using a storyboard. Would you please provide a code example?

Comment: What is your purpose for passing a view controller as a property like that? I don't get it, if it's a model, it will make sense. In case you want to inject a new controller and then navigate to it, use a creating pattern like factory.

Comment: It’s just a model of data that I’m trying to inject and use throughout all my views. As I navigate through them I just pass it back and forth. It’s just acting as a container for my variables. The tutorials online show how to do it if you’re using storyboards but don’t have a navigation controller as the initial view controller. I can’t figure out how to inject the Model Controller (BidDetailsController) from AppDelegate through the Navigation Controller to my home screen, HomeViewController, where I can then use it.